# Can I land in Germany with a single entry Hungarian student visa(Category: D, Valid For: Hungary, 30Days)

Tags: schengen-visas, hungary, student-visas

I got my Hungarian Student visa. 
Initially, it is limited to 30days until I pick up my residence card.
On the visa it states:
Valid for: Hungary
Single entry
Validity: 30 days.

They mentioned in the embassy that I shouldn't leave Hungary until I got my residence permit card.

Can I land in Germany, since I can't get any direct flights to Budapest?

Comment: The title of the linked question says German but it is the same for all Schengen countries.

Answer (score 0):

A D-Visa allows you to transit through Schengen signatory states to get to your final destination.
[Schengen Border Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM%3Al14514) Article 6 states:

> (a) third-country nationals who do not fulfil all the conditions laid down in paragraph 1 but who hold a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall be authorised to enter the territory of the other Member States for transit purposes so that they may reach the territory of the Member State which issued the residence permit or the long-stay visa, unless their names are on the national list of alerts of the Member State whose external borders they are seeking to cross and the alert is accompanied by instructions to refuse entry or transit;

Comment: Thanks Ozzy for the comment. Will I be allowed to exit the airport eg. in Munich to take the train to Budapest?

Comment: Yes, you can exit the Munich airport and take the train (or any other mode of transport) to Hungary.